# Cannot able to add more than one field in firestore database, but it works fine when adding single field

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, chatbot, dialogflow-es

MY index.js file:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

 let action = request.body.result.action;

 var Name = request.body.result.parameters.Name;

 var Answer1 = request.body.result.parameters.Answer1;

  let query = request.body.result.resolvedQuery;

    const parameters = request.body.result.parameters; 

    const inputContexts = request.body.result.contexts; 



     if(action === 'save.name'  || inputContexts == 'welcome'  && action === 'save.answer1' || inputContexts == 'question1'){

                  admin.firestore().collection('users').doc('details').collection('user1').add({
                         name: Name ,
                       answer1 : Answer1

                    }).then(ref => {
                      console.log('Added new user');
                      console.log('name' +Name);
                      console.log('answer1' +Answer1);
                    });

    } 
});
```

I am getting a typerror like **admin.firestore(...).collection(...).document.add is not a function**, When I attempt to store all the user details under a document 'details' . This code is just a attempt to check whether it is possible to add more fields in same document!
I'm using api v1 chatbot

Answer (score 2):

You're getting this error because the method `add` is not supported by the Firestore library.  You're looking for the `set` method.  Change this line:

```
admin.firestore().collection('users').doc('details').collection('user1').add({
```

to this:

```
admin.firestore().collection('users').doc('details').collection('user1').set({
```

Comment: I tried this now I am getting Error like Error: **Invalid use of type "undefined" as a Firestore argument.** How to resolve this?

Comment: have you verified that the value of your variables you are trying to add to Firestore (`Answer1` and `Name`) are not `undefined`?

Comment: I tried adding them one by one..then it's working, when I try to add both the fields together this error occurs?

Comment: If I answered your question please mark it as correct and upvote it, if you have another issue please ask another question and provide the context there. `Invalid use of type "undefined" ` indicated a JavaScript error not a Firestore or Dialogflow issue as originally described in the question.